# Why is Overload Resolution favoring unconstrained template function over a more specific one?

Tags: c++, sfinae, generic-programming, expression-templates

I have this minimal expression template library with a multiplication, i.e.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct mul {
    const T &v1;
    const U &v2;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
mul<T, U> operator*(const T &one, const U &two) {
    std::cout << " called: mul<T, U> operator*(const T &one, const T &two)\n";
    return mul<T, U>{one, two};
}
```

and transpose, i.e.

```
template <typename T>
struct transpose {
    const T &t;
};

template <typename T>
transpose<T> tran(const T &one) {
    return transpose<T>{one};
}
```

I will introduce some types `A` and `B`, where the latter is a subclass of the former:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    T elem;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
    B(T val) : A<T>{val} {}
};
```

Then, I can call my expression template library as follows (with an overload for printing to `std::cout`):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const mul<T, U> &m) {
    os << " unconstrained template \n";
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    B<double> a{2};
    B<double> b{3};
    std::cout << tran(a) * b << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the output :

```
called: mul<T, U> operator*(const T &one, const T &two)
unconstrained template
```

So far so good. Suppose now that I want a specialized treatment for 'transpose of a variable of type `A<T>` times a variable of type `A<T>` for some type `T`', as I had in my `main`. To this end, I will introduce

```
template <typename T>
T operator*(const transpose<A<T>> &one, const A<T> &two) {
    std::cout << " called: T operator*(const A<T> &one, const A<T> &two)\n";
    return one.t.elem * two.elem;
}
```

I run the same `main` function as above, and I still get the same output as above (`unconstrained template`). This is to be expected, since `transpose<B<double>>` is a completely different type compared to `transpose<A<double>>`, so overload resolution picks the unconstrained template version of `operator*`.

(Of course, if I change my variable definitions in `main` to `A` instead of `B`, ADL calls the specialized function and output is `called: T operator*(const A<T> &one, const A<T> &two)` and `6`).

I recently learned about SFINAE, so I expected the following change to the more specific multiplication operator would cause overload resulution to select the specialized function:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A<T>, V>::value, T> operator*(const transpose<V> &one,
                                                               const V &two) {
    std::cout << " called: std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A<T>, V>::value, T> operator*(const "
                 "transpose<V> &one, const V &two)\n";
    return one.t.elem * two.elem;
}
```

**Even using the SFINAE'd `operator*` I still get the `unconstrained template` version. How come? What changes should I make to call the more specialized template function?**

Comment: Maybe my understanding of what ADL is is incorrect, but what this has to do with ADL?

Comment: I thought 'Overload Resolution' and ADL are the same. Apparently, they're not.

Comment: Overloading resolution is choosing between names found incl. those found by ADL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that in the SFINAE overload, `T` is used in a non-deduced context. You're effectively asking the compiler: "Enable this if there exists a `T` such that `A<T>` is a base class of `V`." Existential quantification is a good indicator that what you're asking for cannot be SFINAEd.

You can see this yourself if you disable the unconstrained template, as I did [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04a4c907690b9d91). This forces the compiler to spell out why the other function is not admissible.

You can solve this by making `T` available through your `A` (and thus `B`) classes, like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    using Type = T;
    T elem;
};


template <typename V>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A<typename V::Type>, V>::value, typename V::Type> operator*(const transpose<V> &one,
                                                               const V &two) {
    std::cout << " called: std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A<T>, V>::value, T> operator*(const "
                 "transpose<V> &one, const V &two)\n";
    return one.t.elem * two.elem;
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72735cfc0759777e)

Comment: In fact removing the sfinae, the superfluous template argument then uncommenting the uncontrainted one yield me the correct result.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Yes, that works in the reduced example posted. But note that the OP says that the constrained version should only be used when `V` is derived from `A<T>` for some `A`. Removing the sfinae would make it apply to all transpose-nontranspose pairs.

Comment: Reading this SFINAE it should only allow `typename V` to be `B<T>` but given that `std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value` yields `true` if `std::is_same<Base, Derived>::value` it also allows `A<T>`. Shouldn't there be a check to disallow that, too? If I am understand OP's Intention correctly, that is.

Comment: @StackDanny I understood the OP's question as "how do I word SFINAE for a special case that involves `A<T>` or a type derived from `A<T>`?" That's how I read "Suppose now that I want a specialized treatment for 'transpose of a variable of type `A<T>` times a variable of type `A<T>` for some type `T`', as I had in my `main`." Note that it was a `B<double>` in the `main`, actually.

Comment: @Angew I just find it weird because if you were to remove `struct B` from the code the SFINAE (which strictly asks for a `std::is_base_of` case) will still be called even though there is no inheritance whatsover going on. I just thoughts that's unintentional. I suppose this is to be blamed on the implementation of `std::is_base_of`.

Comment: @Angew You interpreted my intent correctly, although more generally, `A<T>` would be an abstract class.

Comment: @StackDanny `std::is_base_of` effectively models IS-A. To be fair, it's much more common in practice to need to know "are you X or one of its descendants" than "are you derived from X, but not X itself."